# what is the probability that the number of heads is odd?

Tags: probability

> For each $k$, $\mathcal{C}_k$ is biased so that, when tossed, it has probability $\tfrac{1}{(2k+1)}$ of falling heads. If the $n$ coins are tossed, what is the probability that the number of heads is odd? Express the answer as a rational function $n$.

---

One answer posted [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h466472p6419237) goes like this:

> Let $E$ and $O$ be the probabilities that the number of heads is even or odd, respectively. Then $E+O=1$ and
> $E-O=\left(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{4}{5}-\frac{1}{5}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{3}{5}\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2n+1}$so $O=\frac{n}{2n+1}$.

---

$(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{3}),(\frac{4}{5}-\frac{1}{5}),\cdots$ these are essentially the difference in probability of getting a tail and a head in $C_1,C_2,...$, then how, by multiplying these probabilities, we get $E-O$ is not clear to me. Can anyone help provide the derivation/reason behind it? Thanks.